# Document Mng on Redmine: Anyone use DMSF plugin or find an easy way to manage docs in the Files tab with a 'wiki' as a front end?

Tags: document, redmine, redmine-plugins, document-management

I'm looking to use Redmine for document management. I know that Redmine is not ideal for this task but there is already a lot of content on the site so I'd like to utilize it if possible.

Redmine currently does not a have great documents module. The files we've uploaded look to be amended on that specific page and it doesn't seem to be able to move to another page (unless you download and re-upload to the proper page).

**Idea 1**

I see there is a Files section, which could work as a central repository (and you can upload document based on release) however, is there a way to set up a nice-looking 'front-end' page that automatically updates based on new submissions to the Files tab? I envision this front end to be a simple wiki page with the document name, a short description and a links to the file posted in the Files tab.

There are so many documents uploaded to varying pages on the Redmine site. I would only do the whole download and re-upload of files if there was a way to automatically update the 'front end' wiki.

**Idea 2**

I see there is a DMSF plugin for Redmine. Has anyone used this before and has is solved document management issues? I'd like to hear your feedback. Even if DMSF doesn't totally solve my issue, anything is better than what I have now.

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried DMSF for a while, but didn't like it. If you had a permission set wrong, the database breaks and the plugin stops working. Not worth it.

Comment: FYI: it is 2020 now, please, do not be offended by this old comment... today, many people are using DMSF that became quite stable

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion DMSF module is a perfect companion for Redmine. We have adopted it in our company. You can easily deal with document versions, webdav access, custom approval workflow, document modifications notification with the extra value  of being well integrated with Redmine features (roles, dynamic links in Wiki and issue text and notes).